# Getting The variable name '@ErrorMessage' has already been declared

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL server script that contain multiple batches with `try catch`. I ran the script and got the following error:

> The variable name '@ErrorMessage' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

I have the variable declared in multiple places but it's inside each `catch begin .. end` scope. Not sure why it's throwing an error.

I tried moving the declaration before and after `BEGIN TRANSACTION` but I get

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ErrorMessage"

How can I fix this bug?

```
USE [TestWebDb2_Local]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY 

    IF COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[MY_TABL]'), 'MY_REQID', 'ColumnId') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABL] ADD MY_REQID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0) 
    END

    IF COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.MY_TABL'), 'MY_ISCOMPLETED', 'ColumnId') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABL] ADD MY_ISCOMPLETED BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

            SELECT 
                @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

            -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
            -- information about the original error that caused
            -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                       @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                       @ErrorState -- State.
                       );

            PRINT 'The transaction from Alter table is in an uncommittable state.' +
                  ' Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;
END CATCH;
GO 


 BEGIN TRY 
    UPDATE [dbo].[MY_TABL] SET MY_REQID = 20 WHERE PENDTRANS_ABBREV = '1035'


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

            SELECT 
                @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

            -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
            -- information about the original error that caused
            -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                       @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                       @ErrorState -- State.
                       );

            PRINT 'The transaction from UPDATE table is in an uncommittable state.' +
                  ' Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;
END CATCH;


BEGIN TRY
        CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idxReqId ON [dbo].[MY_TABL](MY_REQID)
        PRINT 'Index created'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

            SELECT 
                @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

            -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
            -- information about the original error that caused
            -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                       @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                       @ErrorState -- State.
                       );


            PRINT 'The transaction from Create Index is in an uncommittable state.' +
                  ' Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;
END CATCH;
GO

if XACT_STATE() = 1
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION  
    PRINT 'Transaction committed.';
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables survive for the entire batch, which is most typically separated by `GO` statements; T-SQL does not use `BEGIN` / `END` to determine scope. Hence, the 2nd and 3rd `TRY` / `CATCH` blocks need a `GO` to separate them as that would make them separate batches.